# Why does this infinite solid have infinite surface area, yet finite volume?

Tags: calculus

What is the principle at play?
Differing degrees?

[image]

Comment: See [Torricelli's trumpet : Apparent paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn#Apparent_paradox).

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Gabriel's Horn is not so strange](https://blog.plover.com/math/gabriels-horn.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a gallon of paint that you can roll out as thin as you please, then you can paint any wall, no matter how large.

Comment: The great 20th century mathematician John von Neumann once said to  a student, "Young man,in mathematics one does not understand things. One merely gets used to them."

Comment: ok, but then why is the room finite ?

Comment: Finite 3D volume equals infinite 2D area.

Answer (score 2):

In 3-D there is no positive lower limit to the ratio of volume to area for a bounded surface. E.g. for an arbitrarily narrow piece of a hose. So if you can patch together a sequence of bounded surfaces with volume-to-area ratios $V_n/A_n\to 0$ (as $n\to \infty$)  such that $\sum_nV_n<\infty =\sum_nA_n$ then you have a result as in Gabriel's Horn.

Let $x$ be the L-to-R co-ordinate along the direction of the red axis. For $n\in \Bbb Z^+ $ the area $A_n$ of the part of Gabriel's Horn  between $x=n$ and $x=n+1$ is more than the area  of the curved wall of a cylinder of length $1$ and radius $1/(n+1),$ which is $\frac {2\pi}{n+1},$ while the volume $V_n$ of that same
part of Gabriel's Horn is less than  the volume of a cylinder of length $1$ and radius $1/n,$ which is $\frac {2\pi}{n^2}.$ So for the total area $A$ and volume $V$ we have $$V<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2\pi}{n^2}<\infty =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {2\pi}{n+1}\le A .$$

Comment: Some fast-food chains serve salt obtained from a 100+  year-old process that grows narrow conical salt crystals from brine. So  a greater proportion of a sprinkle of their salt will directly contact your taste buds than will occur with common cubical salt crystals. They haven't yet achieved $ V/A=0.$